# Replacing comma with dot in WP php function

Tags: php

My WP posts show a price on the frontend, taken from a advanced custom field (price-tag) found on each post in the backend. The input could be "5000". I want to format it to show like this on the frontend: "5.000€".

So far I am using this code in my `functions.php` file, which adds the comma at thousands, but I want that comma to be a dot:

```
add_filter('acf/format_value/name=price-tag', 'fix_number', 20, 3);
function fix_number($value, $post_id, $field) { 
    $value = number_format($value); 
    return $value; 
}
```

How do I alter the code to also include the replace function?

I tried adding this to the code above but it doesn't work:

```
str_replace(',', '.', $value);
```

And finally, how do I add a "€" at the end of the price?

Comment: `$value = number_format($value);` is the line you want to look at :) Check out the [man page on number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for a hint before someone answers

Comment: Your second question can be solved by performing string manipulation on `return $value;`

Comment: Nice thanks a lot IsThisJavascript. First part working now:

Comment: add_filter('acf/format_value/name=price-tag', 'fix_number', 20, 3);
function fix_number($value, $post_id, $field) {
  $value = number_format($value, 0, ',', '.');
  return $value;
}

Answer (score 0):

Ok think i have it - this works now:

```
add_filter('acf/format_value/name=price-tag', 'fix_number', 20, 3); 
function fix_number($value, $post_id, $field) { 
$value = number_format($value, 0, ',', '.'); 
$value = substr_replace($value, '€', 30, 0); 
return $value; 
}
```

Comment: You should ideally stick to one question per topic and avoid posting multiple answers. 
The solution I was trying to push you towards was: `return $value."€";` (or better yet, `return $value."&euro;";`)

Comment: Ok my bad - will keep that in mind for the future. Thanks for the help anyway, it guided me to the solution i was looking for.